# How to disable command button while the page is being processed by other action?

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton, ajax

I have `apex:commandButton` and `apex:selectList`.
When the user selects an item in `apex:selectList`, it takes some time to process the request. While the request is being processed, I'd like to disable the Submit button of the form. How to do that?

Here is the Submit button:

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
        <apex:commandButton id="submit_button" value="Submit" action="{!clickSubmit}" rerender="results_wrapper" status="status_message"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

And the select list:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!productType}" size="1">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!productTypeItems}"/>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!onChangeFilter}" rerender="main_form" status="status_message"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

**UPDATE**
The issue was solved by implementing Saroj Bera's example.

Here is the working `apex:commandButton` code:

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
    <apex:actionStatus id="submit-button-status">
        <apex:facet name="start">
            <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!clickCalculate}" disabled="true"/>
        </apex:facet>       
        <apex:facet name="stop">
            <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!clickCalculate}" rerender="results_wrapper" status="status_message"/>
        </apex:facet>       
    </apex:actionStatus>    
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

And the `apex:selectList`:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!productType}" size="1">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!productTypeItems}"/>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!onChangeFilter}" rerender="main_form" status="submit-button-status"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `apex:actionStatus` tag to do this. Here is a working example as per your requirement. When you select a value from first dropdown, the command button will be disabled till the process is complete. I have added 3 secs delay to simulate the situation. Hope this will help.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="loadingSpinnerCtrl3">
  <apex:form id="form">
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
        <apex:actionStatus id="SaveButtonStatus">
          <apex:facet name="stop">
            <apex:outputPanel >
              <apex:commandButton action="{!doSave}" value="Save"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
          </apex:facet>
          <apex:facet name="start">
            <apex:outputPanel >
              <apex:commandButton value="Save" disabled="true"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
          </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:selectList id="selected_list" value="{!dropdown1}" required="false" size="1">
        <apex:selectOption itemvalue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemvalue="1" itemLabel="First"/>
        <apex:selectOption itemvalue="2" itemLabel="Second"/>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="dropdown2" action="{!spin}" status="SaveButtonStatus"/>
      </apex:selectList>
      <apex:selectList id="dropdown2" required="false"  size="1">
        <apex:selectOption itemvalue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}" />
      </apex:selectList>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
  <apex:pageMessages />
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class loadingSpinnerCtrl3 {


    public String dropdown1{get; set;}
    public List<SelectOption> options;

    public PageReference doSave() {
        return null;
    }

    public void spin() {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error Message.'));
        if(dropdown1 == '1'){
            options = new List<SelectOption>();
            options.add(new SelectOption('1','Value 1'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('2','Value 2'));        
        }else if (dropdown1 == '2'){
            options = new List<SelectOption>();
            options.add(new SelectOption('3','Value 3'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('4','Value 4'));        
        }   
        long now = datetime.now().gettime();
        while(datetime.now().gettime()-now<3000); // Busy loop for 3000 ms to simulate delay
    }
    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        return options;
    }    
}
```

Comment: @justasd If it was the answer can you please mark it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **apex:actionStatus** to disable/enable the command button during an AJAX request.

```
<apex:actionStatus id="status_message" startText="Processing..." onStart="disableButton()" onStop="enableButton()"/>
```

Give a **styleClass** attribute to the **commandButton**, so that you can refer it in Javascript.

```
<apex:commandButton id="submit_button" value="Submit" action="{!clickSubmit}" rerender="results_wrapper" status="status_message" styleClass="btnStatus"/>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
    <script>
       function disableButton() {
   $('.btnStatus').attr('disabled',true);
}

function enableButton() {
   $('.btnStatus').attr('disabled',false);
}
</script>
```

Don't forget to include jQuery in your Visualforce Page

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. Good idea but somehow it does not work. JavaScript functions "disableButton" and "enableButton" are being  called, I checked it. But the line document.getElementByClass('.btnStatus').disabled = true; is not working. I also tried getting element by Id, but disabled = true didn't work either.

Comment: A small mistake on my part. It is actually **document.getElementsByClassName()** instead of document.getElementByClass. However, if you are using firefox, not all versions support this.
Hence, it is better to use jQuery, which is much simple and compatible in all browsers. I have changed the code.

Comment: Thanks again. Getting the DOM element of a button was not a problem. The problem is that setting "disabled" attribute to "false" somehow does not work. I tried using plain JavaScript and also tried your example using jQuery.